# Illegal datatype context (use DatatypeContexts): TypeFunctor f

Tags: haskell

```
--{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}

class TypeFunctor f where
 mapf :: (a-> b)->(f a-> fb)

data TypeFunctor f => Fix f = In (f (Fix f))
out :: TypeFunctor f => Fix f -> f (Fix f)
out (In x) = x

fold :: TypeFunctor f => (f a -> a) -> (Fix f -> a)
fold f = f . mapf (fold f) . out
```

I am getting the following error message:

> error:
>       Illegal datatype context (use DatatypeContexts): TypeFunctor f =>   | 4 | data TypeFunctor f => Fix f = In (f (Fix f))   |
>   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

What is a Problem?

---

**edited**:

```
newtype Fix f = In (f (Fix f))

out :: Functor f => Fix f -> f (Fix f)
out (In x) = x

fold :: Functor f => (f a -> a) -> (Fix f -> a)
fold f = f . fmap (fold f) . out
```

Comment: When I am using `DatatypeContexts`, I get following error : `-XDatatypeContexts is deprecated:`

Comment: It's an obsolete feature, no longer recommended. Just use `data Fix f = In (f (Fix f))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

First, you commented the extension out. This does nothing:

```
-- {-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}
```

This enables the `DatatypeContexts` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}
```

Second, as the warning suggests, `DatatypeContexts` should not be used anymore. Instead, functions should require the constraints that are relevant to them.